# Troubles with hiding cells with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table where I want to hide cells for more than a certain week.
For this I use a function hideWeekCells. It works well when I am using just number instead of *currentweek* here -> *_el.dataset.week > 24* (it works well), but when I tried to change it to dynamic variable current week. There is a problem. Function starts to hide cells at 17 weeks instead of stopping at 24 weeks.

```
function hideWeekCells(){

        const myAnchor = document.getElementById("myAnchor"); 
        currentweek = myAnchor.dataset.currentweek;     
        
        let weeks = document.querySelectorAll("[data-week]")
        //console.log( 'weeks : ', weeks ); 
        let weeks_array = Array.from( weeks ).filter((_el)=> _el.dataset.week > current week);
        console.log( 'weeks_array final : ', weeks_array ); 
        weeks_array.forEach(element => {
          element.style.display = 'none';
        });       
};
```

I tried to convert currentweek to numbers with *currentweek.valueOf();*, but it did not help.

Is it a problem with javascript and my function or maybe it is a problem with my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataset` returns a string by default, so you need to convert them to numbers by [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) for your number comparisons.

Another side note, you should define `currentweek` with `const` or `let` to scope that variable into the function.

```
function hideWeekCells(){

        const myAnchor = document.getElementById("myAnchor"); 
        const currentweek = Number(myAnchor.dataset.currentweek);     
        
        let weeks = document.querySelectorAll("[data-week]")
        //console.log( 'weeks : ', weeks ); 
        let weeks_array = Array.from( weeks ).filter((_el)=> Number(_el.dataset.week) > currentweek);
        console.log( 'weeks_array final : ', weeks_array ); 
        weeks_array.forEach(element => {
          element.style.display = 'none';
        });       
};
```